# How to implement VP9 codec in a free open source Peer-to-peer communication app?

Tags: p2p, codec, opus, speex, vp9

So there is this Application RetroShare which currently uses speex codec and libav codec for VOIP communications.
They expect a new improved VoIP cross platform codec as the old one aren’t fitting the bill.
What I’ve landed on is implementing VP9 and OPUs codec for better audio and video quality over communications.

How can I approach that ?
Can anyone please tell me is there any tutorial for implementing VP9 codec ? I couldn’t find one!

Or can anyone here tell me how to implement codecs in a Peer-to-peer applications ?

And is my approach right ?

Comment: You probably don't want to implement the codec yourself, that would take man-years of work. Just use a library.

Comment: So I can just use the library (For example using libaom Library made for AV1 codec) to implement a improved VoIP codec in the sample application I’m talking about ? The app is using an outdated VoIP codec for Calls and video conferring currently.